# Checking if both keys match isn't working right

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, combobox

This application works as if you were playing the lottery, you pick 5 numbers from a comboBox, click a button to generate the 5 key numbers and then you press another button to check the results (after you introduce the prize monei on the textbox below, AKA "prémio").

[image: Main Form]

The button that does the checking is the highlighted one **Verificar Prémio**.

Here's it's code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox1.Text!="Prémio em €")
    {
        int contador = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            string posicao = i.ToString();

            for (int c = 1; c <= 5; c++)
            {
                string poschave = c.ToString();
                if (listBox1.Items.IndexOf(posicao) == 
                    listBox2.Items.IndexOf(poschave))
                {
                    contador = contador + 1;

                }

            }

            i = int.Parse(posicao);

            double valor;
            double premio = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            if (contador == 5)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Parabens ganhou o 1º premio acertou 5 números 
                    o seu prémio é de " + premio + "€");
            }
            else
            {
                if (contador == 4)
                {
                    valor = premio * 0.75;
                    MessageBox.Show(" Acertou 4 numeros o seu premio é: " + 
                       valor + "€");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (contador == 3)
                    {
                        valor = premio * 0.5;
                        MessageBox.Show("Acertou 3 numeros o seu premio é: " + 
                           valor + "€");
                    }
                    else
                        if (contador <= 2)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(" Infelizmente nao ganhou, 
                               nada tente outra vez");
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Whatever I do, it always shows the messageBox saying I got all 5 correct...

EDIT:

listBox1 is the one on the left,  (3, 9, 17, 20, 10), you choose them from the combobox and when you Click "Apostar" it is added to it.

listBox2 is the box on the right.

EDIT2: 
By replacing

```
for (int c = 1; c <= 5; c++)
            {
                string poschave = c.ToString();
                if (listBox1.Items.IndexOf(posicao) == listBox2.Items.IndexOf(poschave))
                {
                    contador = contador + 1;

                }

            }
```

with

```
                foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                // Convert it to string to avoid object reference comparison. Not 100% 
                // sure if this is needed
                string value = item.ToString();
                if (listBox2.Items.Contains(value))
                    contador++;
            }
```

The error doesnt show anymore however it still isnt working properly, my guess is that the program is checking if they match, then get the result, therefore it always show "you won nothing" 5 times in a row...

How can I fix this?

Comment: You checking indexes "if (listBox1.Items.IndexOf(posicao) == listBox2.Items.IndexOf(poschave))" shouldnt you check values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand Spanish(?) so it's very hard to understand your code (please use english variable names, even if you have a localized UI)

However, one cause of the problem could be this line:

```
listBox1.Items.IndexOf(posicao) == listBox2.Items.IndexOf(poschave)
```

In case neither `posicao` or `poschave` is found in their respective listboxes, -1 will be returned and the expression will be true (i.e. `contador` will be incremented). I'm guessing this is not the desired behavior.

If you instead want to check if an item in the left listbox is also available in the right, then you could do:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == "Prémio em €")
        return;
    int numMatches = 0;
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        if (listBox2.Items.Contains(item))
            numMatches++;
    }
    // numMatches will now contain the number of elements in the left 
    // listbox that also exist in the right listbox
    if (numMatches > 2)
    {
        double premio = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        double prize = 0;
        if (numMatches == 5)
          prize = premio * 1.0;
        if (numMatches == 4)
          prize = premio * 0.75;
        else 
          prize = premio * 0.5;
        // Use string.Format() instead to get fancier formatting of numbers
        Messagebox.Show ("Sweet, you got " + numMatches + " out of 5 correct numbers. Your prize is " + prize + "€");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, not enough matches - you win nothing!");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The reason you get 5 message boxes is because you have the call to `Messagebox.Show()` inside a for loop that loops five times. I've updated the code sample above to do what I think you want your button callback to do

Comment: Also, why the line 'i = int.Parse(posicao);'? posiaco is already the stringified version of i, and it's usually not a good idea to manipulate the loop variable in a for-loop. And you might consider replacing the nested ifs with a switch-case expression

Comment: hm how should I go about doing that? Sorry but I only started programming a while ago and it's the first time I do something like this

Comment: @Madcowe: I'm not 100% sure what you want the code to do, but I added an example which I *think* is what you want

Comment: @isak as I commented above, this code doesnt give any errors either, but I think the program is going untill then end and then repeating, therefore saying 5 times "you didnt win"

Comment: @isak thanks a lot, I'll check back on you as soon as I test it

Comment: @isak It improved a bit, it does not show anymore 5 windows saying I got nothing, however, even if I get them all to be the same I get the message saying "Sorry, not enough matches - you win nothing!"...

Comment: @Madcowe: can you step through the code in the debugger to see where it goes wrong? Are you saying that you always get the message "Sorry not enough matches"?

Comment: @isak yes I always get that message, as a side note, I am getting this warning: "Warning 1 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.CSharp". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. Lotaria
"  but I dont know if that has much influence... and what do you mean by stepping through the code?   and also this related warning: "Warning 2 The referenced component 'Microsoft.CSharp' could not be found.  
"

Comment: Alright, I actually wrote a winforms app that has the same logic as your app and debugged it. If you remove the conversion to string in the first `foreach()` loop the Contains() call will work and the count will be correct

Comment: not sure I got it, I change "      string value = item.ToString();
      if (listBox2.Items.Contains(value))
          numMatches++;" **to** "      if (listBox2.Items.Contains(item))
          numMatches++;" ?

Comment: Yes. I've already updated the code sample in my answer to use the correct code.

Answer (score 2):

Your source is way too complicated, you have two loops, one integer > string followed by string > integer... try this:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (listBox2.Items.IndexOf(listBox1.Items[i]) > 0)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
// count is 0 - 5
```

You only check for 5 numbers of the left ListBox if it is in the right ListBox.

Comment: I replaced: "
            for (int c = 1; c <= 5; c++)
            {
                string poschave = c.ToString();
                if (listBox1.Items.IndexOf(posicao) == 
                    listBox2.Items.IndexOf(poschave))
                {
                    contador = contador + 1;

                }

            }" 
   with the one you wrote there but I got the following error message:    Error 1 Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.Items' cannot be used like a method. C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\C#\qwerty\Form2.cs 106 57 Lotaria

Comment: @Madcowe: try square brackets instead: `listBox1.Items[i]`

Comment: @IsakSavo The error doesnt show anymore however it still isnt working properly, my guess is that the program is checking if they match, then get the result, therefore it always show "you won nothing" 5 times in a row...

Comment: @Isak Thanks, forgot to recheck syntax